# Call to a member function update() on string

Tags: laravel

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $user =  Auth::user()->name ;
    $user->input($request->input('name'));
    $user->save;

}
```

Comment: None of the code here would cause that error.

Answer (score 4):

`$user` is a string. Change your code to this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user =  Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: That's definitely a problem, but I don't think OP's even getting to *that* problem. They'd get "Call to a member function **input()** on string"...

Comment: Based on what OP shared: `$user->input($request->input('name'));` the `$user` is a string, because `$user = Auth::user()->name;`. In another words `$user` is actually a user's name, which is string. This logic would throw error when you want to access `input` method on a string (`$user`).

Comment: Right, but it wouldn't say "Call to a member function update() on string", it'd say "Call to a member function input() on string" in that case. (Unless OP made a mistake in their question title.)

Comment: That would be so weird. I don't see `update` method called in the code, but yeah maybe that's a different story. The code itself is not runnable in my local, trying to make it runs but as you said, none of my trial could replicate the issue.

Comment: Yeah. If OP's title is accurate, OP has *two* problems. I've upvoted you, incidentally, as you've definitely identified *a* problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user_id =  Auth::user()->id ;
    $user=User::find($user_id);
    $user->input($request->input('name'));
    $user->save;
}
```

OR

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user =  Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Just a note: The second code block will save you a query. The first will query the `users` table twice for the same info.